# How can convert this query in to laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC) AS t GROUP BY numbers;

Comment: did my answer help? Please mark whichever the correct answer was as such (click the checkbox next to it).

Answer (score 0):

For the converting sub query you can use DB:raw in select

```
Model::select(DB::raw("Your query") as t)->groupBy('number')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::query()
    ->fromSub(function($query) {
        $query->from('table')
            ->orderByDesc('time');
    }, 't')
    ->groupBy('numbers')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
DB::table('table')
  ->orderBy('time')
  ->groupBy('numbers')
  ->get();
```